# Problems with pd.read_csv

Tags: python, csv

I have Anaconda 3 on Windows 10. I am using pd.read_csv() to load csv files but I get error messages.  To begin with I tried `df = pd.read_csv('C:\direct_marketing.csv')` which worked and the file was imported.

Then I tried `df = pd.read_csv('C:\tutorial.csv')` and I received the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-ce208cc2684f>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\tutorial.csv')

  File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 315, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 645, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 799, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1213, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 358, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:3427)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 628, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:6861)

OSError: File b'C:\tutorial.csv' does not exist
```

Then I moved the file to a new folder and renamed it and again used read.csv() to import it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\test.csv')
```

This time I received a different error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-03c6d380c174>", line 1
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\test.csv')
                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Could you help me understand what is going on and how to handle this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the backslashes:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\test.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

try use two back-slash '\' instead of '\'. It might have take it as a escape sign.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add `r` before the path i.e. `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\test.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake and put

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

instead of

```py
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\test.csv')
```

I saved the file in the same directory to anaconda